# MediaWiki hidden subcategories

Tags: categories, mediawiki

Does a MediaWiki functionality or extension exist to mark a category tree, i.e., subcategories of a certain category, as hidden?

I know about `__HIDDENCAT__` to hide a category, but it has no effect on subcategories. If I use it for subcategories explicitly, they do no longer create a category tree, but are all sorted in a flat structure directly below 'hidden categories'.

Comment: Part of why that would be difficult is that the MediaWiki category system is not a tree. It's not even guaranteed to be acyclic.

Comment: _If I use it for subcategories explicitly, they do no longer create a category tree_ - that's probably some sort of misunderstanding. The shape of the category graph is not affected by whether some of the categories are marked as hidden.